# Getting feature_importances_ from RandomForestRegressor() or RandomForestClassifier() for regression and classification problems

Tags: scikit-learn, regression, classification, random-forest, feature-selection

There is a difference between the `feature_importance_` matrices from `RandomForestClassifier()` and `RandomForestRegressor()`.

So if I want to get best features for Classification/Regression problems, which one should I choose based on the class/reg problem?

Answer (score 1):

`feature_importance_` gives the relative importance of the random-forest. Regarding the choice between regressor or classifier, it will depend on your target and the problem that you are solving. If your target is discrete, you probably have a classification problem. If it is continuous, you have a regression problem.

However, be aware that `feature_importance_` have limitation and should be used carefully. You are better off using the `permutation_importance`. You can look at the example which explains the issue with low cardinality feature for which the importance is reported low with `feature_importance_`: https://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/inspection/plot_permutation_importance.html#sphx-glr-auto-examples-inspection-plot-permutation-importance-py